# Implement OnClickListener in DatePickerDialog to do something is not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-datepicker

I'm trying to make a DatePickerDialog to change a TextView. But I also want to display a Toast when the user click on the "Ok" button.

So, I implemented `DatePickerDialog.OnClickListener` and `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` and I override both method. But nothing happen when I click the "Ok" button on the DatePicker. Any idea ?

Thank in advance, here is my DatePickerFragment :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, DatePickerDialog.OnClickListener {

    public static int year_x;
    public static int month_x;
    public static int day_x;
    public static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        final int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        /*
        // When I do that way and not implement DatePickerDialog.OnClickListener the date is not updated in my TextView switcherDateDay
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        */
        return dialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        year_x  = view.getYear();
        month_x = view.getMonth();
        day_x = view.getDayOfMonth();

        calendar.set(year_x, month_x, day_x);
        ScheduleCalendar scheduleCal = new ScheduleCalendar(calendar, 0);

        TextView switcherDateDay = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.schedule_switcher_date);
        TextView switcherCurrentDay = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.schedule_switcher_current_day);
        switcherDateDay.setText(String.format("%s %s %s", scheduleCal.getDayName(), scheduleCal.getDayNo(), scheduleCal.getMonthName()));
        switcherCurrentDay.setText(ScheduleSwitcherFragment.statueOfWeek(scheduleCal));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your Toast in onDateSet method of datepicker dialog

Answer (score 0):

check out this example for a conclusive answer https://github.com/tkunstek/android-big-nerd-ranch/blob/master/20_CameraImage_CriminalIntent/src/com/bignerdranch/android/criminalintent/DatePickerFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way, I believe you'll need to implement the DialogInterface.OnClickListener() (Not DatePickerDialog.OnClickListener()). Although I'm not sure why you wouldn't do it the way it's done in the commented out code in the OnCreateDialog method.

Also, you'll still need to add an OnClickListener to the button you're hoping capture clicks for.